# Extends base.twig when it is with passed entity

Tags: templates, twig, entity, symfony4, extends

I am making some small project with Symfony, but now I have a question about `base.twig.html`, and does it should be passed  with some entity in it. I am using Symfony 4.

Lets say I have some entity `MainCategory` with:

1. id
2. name
3. info
4. slug

Then from my Route `/`, I use `MainCategoryRepository` to get all records for that entity, then render the `base.twig` with the passed records. 
Then in navigation bar, I loop over all records and make links with the entity.name.

After that in another Route "/{slug}", i render another twig file which extends the base one. But here i am not using the repository, i use just the Entity - MainCategory, because the 'slug' is unique field and it will get only that record. 
And here is the problem, i am just passing one record, but the navigation bar from the 'base.twig' loop over all records and here I get an error:

> Variable "mainCategories" does not exist.

Here is my code:

**Route "/"**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="app_homepage")
 */
public function homepage(MainCategoryRepository $mainCategoryRepository)
{
    $mainCategories = $mainCategoryRepository->findAll();
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
        'mainCategories' => $mainCategories,
    ]);
}
```

**"base.html.twig"**

```
{% for mainCategory in mainCategories %}
    <li>
       <a href="{{ path('category_show', {'slug': mainCategory.slug}) }}">
       {{ mainCategory.name }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Route "/{slug}"**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slug}",  name="category_show")
 */
public function categoryShow(MainCategory $mainCategory)
{
    return $this->render('show.html.twig',
        [
            'mainCategory' => $mainCategory,
        ]
    );
}
```

**"show.html.twig"**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
        <p>{{ mainCategory.Info }}</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

ERROR:

> Variable "mainCategories" does not exist.

So it is good idea to pass any entity in `base.twig`? I can pass all records in the second twig file, but that means I have to do it in every template which extends the `base.twig`.

Comment: I think you should better using renderController
[https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html]

Comment: @hous, Thanks for that, I didn't know it !

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, dont know is it perfect or the right solution, but it works.

I made one Service with a method in which I return all records from MainCategory Entity.

**MainCategoryLoaderService**

```
protected $mainCategoryRepository;

public function __construct(MainCategoryRepository $mainCategoryRepository)
{
    $this->mainCategoryRepository = $mainCategoryRepository;
}

public function getAllMainCategories()
{
    return $this->mainCategoryRepository->findAll();
}
```

Then in the file `config/packages/twig.yaml` I made one global variable:

**Global Variable**

```
globals:
    globalMainCategory: '@App\Service\MainCategoryLoaderService'
```

After that in `base.html.twig` I made one variable in which I will have all main categories:

**Twig Variable**

```
{% set mainCategories = globalMainCategory.getAllMainCategories() %}
```

And then just loop over that variable.